# How to sort a CSV file using python

Tags: python, arrays, csv

I am trying to make a leader board for my python program
I have sorted out writing the different scores to the leader board already
However, I am having trouble finding a way that I can sort this data
(Highest score at the top and lowest at the bottom)

Also, I am sorry but I do not have any code that is even vaguely functional, everything I have tried has just been incorrect

Also I only have limited access to modules as it is for a school project which makes it even harder for me (I have CSV,Random,Time,)

Thank you so much
I would really appreciate any help I can recieve

Comment: provide code, data, example etc.. noone can help you without that

Comment: You're going to want to go and attempt this and come back when you have a problem. If you have issues visualizing it ask your supervisor, stackoverflow isn't really for homework/larger issues like this

Comment: The least you could provide is an example of input and desired output. Please take a look at how to provide [mcve]

Comment: Please let us know which version of Python you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can read in the file with pandas, sort it by a column, and overwrite the old csv with the new values. The code would look similar to this:

```
import pandas as pd

path = your_file_path

df = pd.read_csv(path)

df = df.sort_values(by=["column_name"], ascending=False)

df.to_csv(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be done in 3 parts using standard Python:

1. Read all of the data (assuming it has a header row). A `csv_reader()` is used to parse your file and read in each row as a list of values. By calling `list()` it will read all rows as a list of rows.
2. Sort the data
3. Write all of the data (add back the header first), this time using a `csv.writer()` to automatically take your list of rows and write the correct format to the file.

This can be done using Python's `csv` library which you say you can use. Secondly you need to tell the `sort()` function how to sort your rows. In this example it assumes the scores are in the second column. The `csv` library will read each row as a list of values (starting from 0), so the score in this example is column 1. The `key` parameter gives `sort()` a function to call for each row that it is sorting. The function receives a row and returns which parts of the row to sort on, that way you don't have to sort on the first column. `lambda` is just shorthand for writing a single line function, it takes a parameter `x` and returns the elements from the row to sort on. Here we use a Python tuple to return two elements, the score and the name. First convert the score string `x[1]` into an integer. Adding a `-` will make the highest score sort to the top. `x[0]` then uses the `Name` column to sort for cases where two scores are the same:

```
import csv

with open('scores.csv', newline='') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    header = next(csv_input)
    data = list(csv_input)

data.sort(key=lambda x: (-int(x[1]), x[0]))

with open('scores_sorted.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(header)
    csv_output.writerows(data)
```

So for a sample CSV file containing:

```
name,score
fred,5
wilma,10
barney,8
betty,4
dino,10
```

You would get a sorted output CSV looking like:

```
name,score
dino,10
wilma,10
barney,8
fred,5
betty,4
```

Note, `dino` and `wilma` both have the same score, but `dino` is alphabetically first.

This assumes you are using Python 3.x